# Output python script in django dashboard app

Tags: python, django

Currently I'm learning to work with the Django framework. I'm trying to make a dashboard that can collect some output of scripts I want to make (in Python). I can't really find a conclusive answer to how to pipe the output of a python script through Django in my app. For instance, I want a script that runs a couple of ARP calls and pings in a network and have the output in a dashboard. Of course python is probably not the only language I'm going to use for scripting, maybe I will use some Bash or Golang also.

I hope someone is able to help my in the right direction.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I have done this for a coding portal that I made.

What I did is, opened a thread that executed code and put the output in a file that was linked to a model filefield

Then I simply collected the contents of the file in the template (dashboard in your case)

If interested,
[models.py](https://github.com/adwait-thattey/ase1_prj/blob/master/questions/models.py) (Check for Submission and Result model)
[Code processing file](https://github.com/adwait-thattey/ase1_prj/blob/master/questions/background_tasks.py) (This is the file that actually runs the code and collects)

I was in a hurry when I made this. The way I have processed code is highly inefficient and should not be used. But you will get the idea

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Note sure if I want to learn how to do this from a highly inefficient example. Currently, I'm left a bit in the dark on how to do this from scratch, so an example that is really concrete and a best practice to start learning it would be the best. I do, however, thank you for taking the time for me. I appreciate that!

Comment: No I meant the way I process code is inefficient. You can look at the file to see how to use threading and subprocess module to what you want